# MPI_COMM_SIZE error at compile time: A non-optional actual argument must be present when invoking a procedure with an explicit interface

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel

I'm quite new to fortran, and I'm in the process of debugging a large software package for a research project.

In an attempt to fix a different bug, I was instructed to swap out
`include 'mpif.h'` --> `use mpi` in all the source files.  I whipped up a bash script to do this reversibly in the source and I did the modification.

Then I started getting errors in all the calls `call MPI_WTIME(ierr)` telling me I had too many arguments.  Confused, I followed my nose and removed the argument `ierr` and the compile time errors went away.  Now I'm stuck on the following:

`(1315): error #6631: A non-optional actual argument must be present when invoking a procedure with an explicit interface.   [IERROR]
      CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)`

This is the source for the subroutine in question.  I don't see whats wrong with this call to MPI_COMM_SIZE and I don't understand what the deal is with "explicit references" or "non-optinoal actual arguments".  Any thoughts?

```
1284       Subroutine Distribute_Partitioning_1B_2B(OP_MAP_STARTS1B,
1285      &                        OP_MAP_STOPS1B,
1286      &                        OP_MAP_STARTS,
1287      &                        OP_MAP_STOPS,CI_MAP_STARTS1B,
1288      &                        CI_MAP_STOPS1B,CI_MAP_STARTS,
1289      &                        CI_MAP_STOPS,
1290      &                        NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B,NPROC_OP2B)
1291 
1292       USE   mpi !! *storm*
1293       IMPLICIT NONE
1294 
1295       INTEGER :: NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B,NPROC_OP2B,MYID
1296 
1297       INTEGER :: CI_MAP_STARTS1B(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B)
1298       INTEGER :: CI_MAP_STOPS1B(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B)
1299       INTEGER :: OP_MAP_STARTS1B(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B)
1300       INTEGER :: OP_MAP_STOPS1B(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP1B)
1301 
1302       INTEGER :: CI_MAP_STARTS(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP2B)
1303       INTEGER :: CI_MAP_STOPS(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP2B)
1304       INTEGER :: OP_MAP_STARTS(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP2B)
1305       INTEGER :: OP_MAP_STOPS(NPROC_CI,NPROC_OP2B)
1306 
1307 !! *storm* !!      INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
1308 
1309       INTEGER ::  ierr,NPROC_2B
1310 
1311 
1312       NPROC_2B=NPROC_OP2B*NPROC_CI
1313 
1314       CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MYID,ierr)
1315       CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
1316 
1317 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1318 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1319 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1320 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1321       CALL MPI_BCAST(OP_MAP_STARTS1B,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP1B,
1322      .               MPI_INTEGER,NPROC_2B,
1323      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1324       CALL MPI_BCAST(OP_MAP_STOPS1B,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP1B,
1325      .               MPI_INTEGER,NPROC_2B,
1326      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1327       CALL MPI_BCAST(CI_MAP_STOPS1B,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP1B,
1328      .               MPI_INTEGER,NPROC_2B,
1329      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1330       CALL MPI_BCAST(CI_MAP_STARTS1B,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP1B,
1331      .               MPI_INTEGER,NPROC_2B,
1332      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1333 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1334 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1335 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1336 !!!! Distribute data necessary for one-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1337 
1338 
1339 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1340 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1341 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1342 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1343       CALL MPI_BCAST(OP_MAP_STARTS,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP2B,MPI_INTEGER,0,
1344      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1345       CALL MPI_BCAST(OP_MAP_STOPS,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP2B,MPI_INTEGER,0,
1346      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1347       CALL MPI_BCAST(CI_MAP_STOPS,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP2B,MPI_INTEGER,0,
1348      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1349       CALL MPI_BCAST(CI_MAP_STARTS,NPROC_CI*NPROC_OP2B,MPI_INTEGER,0,
1350      &               MPI_COMM_WORLD,IERR)
1351 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1352 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1353 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1354 !!!! Distribute data necessary for two-body Partitioning among *ALL* procs 
1355 
1356       End Subroutine Distribute_Partitioning_1B_2B
1357 
1358       END MODULE CIPartitioning
1359 
1360
```

For reference, I'm using `ifort_orig 16.0.3` and `impi 2017.1`

Comment: MPI_COMM_SIZE(COMM, SIZE, IERR) takes two non-optional and one optional argument. In your case, MPI_COMM_WORLD is the communicator and the call to MPI_COMM_SIZE will return the size, i.e number of processes associated with that communicator group

Comment: note the third argument is mandatory here because of `USE mpi`. that being said, the third argument is optional but only with Fortran 2008 bindings (e.g. `USE mpi_f08`).

Comment: Oh wow I feel silly now.  The call didn't have the `SIZE` variable at all and was erroneously (when using `include 'mpif.h'`) storing the size into the variable `ierr` would invariably cause big problems down the line.

Thanks for being my second set of eyes on this one.